# Difference between 'hdfs dfs -ls' and 'hdfs dfs -ls /'

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Why `hdfs dfs -ls` points to the different location than `hdfs dfs -ls /`?

It can be clearly seen from below screenshot of two commands give different output:
[image]

What is the main cause of the outputs above?

Comment: I'd guess it points to some kind of home folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official source code [org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Ls.java) . Just search for `DESCRIPTION` word. It will list below statements:-

```
public static final String DESCRIPTION =
 "List the contents that match the specified file pattern. If " +
 "path is not specified, the contents of /user/<currentUser> " +
 "will be listed. For a directory a list of its direct children " +
 "is returned (unless -" + OPTION_DIRECTORY +
 " option is specified)"
```

`hadoop fs -ls`  will list home directory content of current user.

`hadoop fs -ls /` will list direct childs of root directory.

Answer (score 3):

The default location for `-ls` in Hadoop is the home directory of the user, in this case `/user/root`.

Adding the `/` makes the `-ls` command point at the root directory of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` looks for the root Folder of the Hdfs